# FTP only uploading half an image

Tags: image, file-upload, ftp

This is strictly not programming, but I'm really struggling to find a solution!

I use Microsoft Expression Web 4 as a basic editor and to upload to my website via FTP (I have passive FTP ticked and have never had an issue).

Today, when I upload an image (png and less than 200kb) only half is seen on the website, yet the image is whole on my laptop.

*Example: http://chasinged.com/quotes/same-life.html* (**EDIT** Now a good image as I manually uploaded on my file manager in GoDaddy, but this is just a temporary solution and painfully slow.)

(**EDIT** New example: http://chasinged.com/quotes/walk-away.html)

I've tried:

- Re-uploading the image
- Uploading another image which is currently on the site using the same name (also uploads half an image)
- Uploading the image to another "good" page (also uploads half - I now have another page with half an image!)

My uploads are all classed successful by expression web.

Has anyone seen this before, or have a solution?

Thank you

Kitson